# How to prevent overwriting the whole environment field while using YAML anchors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, yaml-anchors

I am writing my docker-compose.yml file and to avoid writing redundant lines especially for using different profiles for dev, uat, prod etc, I was using yaml anchors. Here is a sample for one of the adapters I used for uat and for dev.

```
Adapter:&Adapter
  image:"my-image"
  profiles:
    - uat
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dloader.main=com.my.class"
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=uat
  volumes:
    - /local/path/to/logs:/logs
  depends_on:
    - some_image

Adapter-dev:
  <<: *Adapter
  profiles:
    - dev
  environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

.env file contains:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx3g -Xms3g
```

The key part is that the JAVA_OPTS is a must have in order to run properly. The JAVA_OPTS is stored in a .env file, and I append to the JAVA_OPTS variable to specify my main class. I just found out that doing it in the way above, it overwrites the environment entirely and only passes the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE to my docker container's environment variables. What I expected would be that only SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE would be overwritten, but the JAVA_OPTS would be preserved. How can I only overwrite the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE in my docker-compose.yml without overwriting the JAVA_OPTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific solution used was to utilise a common-services.yml file. This allowed me to only run the services with the specified profile without running the default services. What I did was to extract the default service to an additional yml file like so:

```
#common-services.yml:
services:
  adapter:
    image: "my-image"
    profiles: []
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dloader.main=com.my.class"
    volumes:
      - /local/path/to/logs:/logs
```

and the docker compose yaml will look like:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  adapter-uat:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: adapter
    profiles:
      - uat
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=uat
    depends_on:
      - some_image

  adapter-dev:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: adapter
    profiles:
      - dev
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    depends_on:
      - some_image
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case where I'd use Compose's support for [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/), which are able to [combine per-service settings](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/).  Compose [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) are better for selecting *which* service to run, but not necessarily for controlling *how* to run it.

You'd have a base `docker-compose.yml` file that listed all of the settings that were required in every environment

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  adapter:
    image: "my-image"
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dloader.main=com.my.class"
    volumes:
      - /local/path/to/logs:/logs
    depends_on:
      - some_image
```

Then you'd have a file per environment that added settings for only that environment

```yaml
# docker-compose.uat.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  adapter:
    environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=uat
```

When you go to run `docker-compose` commands, you can then specify both files using `docker-compose -f` options.  Note that you need to specify both files on *every* `docker-compose` invocation; setting a [`$COMPOSE_FILE`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_file) environment variable may be a little easier.

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.uat.yaml up -d
```

There are two versions of the Compose tooling, an older one that runs as a standalone tool and a newer one packaged as a `docker` CLI extension.  This setup will work with both of them.

Answer (score 1):

In Compose you can set up one service to [extend](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/) another.  This does essentially what you're showing with YAML anchors, but it also lets you provide additional settings.

```yaml
version: '2.4'
services:
  adapter:
    image: "my-image"
    profiles: []
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dloader.main=com.my.class"
    volumes:
      - /local/path/to/logs:/logs

  adapter-uat:
    extends:
      service: adapter
    profiles:
      - uat
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=uat
    depends_on:
      - some_image

  adapter-dev:
    extends:
      service: adapter
    profiles:
      - dev
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    depends_on:
      - some_image
```

`depends_on:` is documented to not be reused in `extends:` services, so I've copied it into each per-environment service here.

There are two versions of the Compose tool.  If you are using the older version of the tool (`docker-compose --version` says it's version 1) then be aware that the Compose file format version 3 doesn't include `extends:`; you need to declare a `version: 2.x` at the start of the file and you will be unable to use some Swarm-related features in version 3 of the file format.

Comment: Thanks for this! I personally like the other option, though the workplace objective is to reduce the number of files to keep track of and to not make the docker compose command harder to type.

Comment: I just tested this out, but it seems to run two copies of the adapter, ie adapter and adapter-dev at the same time. This would throw an error if there was any port bindings ie 8080:8080